# Knockout.js: Changing the value of Observable does not change the value of attribute in html

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal

I have a fairly simple file which renders a pencil image like this:

```
define(['durandal/events', 'knockout'], function (events, ko) {

    var pencilVM= function () {
    this.pencilimagepath = ko.observable("img/pencil.png");
    };

    return pencilVM;
});
```

and a html:

```
<div>
 <img data-bind="attr: {src: pencilimagepath}" />
</div>
```

Now when I change the name of the image from pencil.png to someImg.png, the final html rendered in the browser is not updated. It stills stays as "pencil.png"

Comment: can you post your code where you set the pencilimagepath?

Comment: @nemesv I have posted the js which sets the pencilimagepath.

Comment: How do you do the update: `vm.pencilimagepath("new path")` or `vm.pencilimagepage = "new path"`?

Comment: Can you post the code where you change pencilimagepath?

Comment: I just renamed the path from ko.observable("img/pencil.png") to ko.observable("img/someImg.png") in js. I did not do the update through code.

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem. Try to use `CTRL`+`F5` o update your site.

Comment: I thought so too, but CTRL+F5 did not solve the problem. What surprises me is, when I view the source, the html has src="img/pencil.png" even after reloading.

Comment: if you've literally done `model.pencilimagepath = ko.observable('img/someImg.png')` it's not going to work.  You need to update the existing observable, not assign a new one, ie `model.pencilimagepath('img/someImg.png')`.  Generally with knockout, if you find yourself assigning to something that's observable, it's _probably_ wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the browser is caching the image.

Just add the timestamp to your new image source

```
var d = new Date();
this.pencilimagepath("img/someImg.png" + d.getTime());
```

Hope that helps.